# Activity calls a second Activity but result is sent back before the second Activity calls onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, startactivityforresult

I need some help here. Basically, I have an Activity. This uses the `startActivityForResult()` method to call a second Activity (which is part of the same app). The result code for this second Activity returns `RESULT_CANCEL` *before* the `onCreate()` method of the second Activity is called.

This is bewildering me. If I change the Intent and call the Android Messaging App Activity and not my own Activity I get the result code correctly *after* that Activity finishes.

It's pretty obvious to me that when you call your own Activity for a result you must do something different.

Testing on Android V2.2

Comment: Are you sure that the second activity is called?

Comment: Yes, the onCreate() method is called and the window displays. Other than getting the result code WAY to early, everything works perfectly.

Comment: It turns out this problem is related to the Launch Mode of the applications Activities as defined in the applications manifest.xml file. I will write up a solution or explanation shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have found the solution to this.

If you have a launchMode of "singleTask" or "singleInstance" then you cannot receive a result from an Activity that you launch from your application. It will return immediately as RESULT_CANCEL. By changing the launchMode of the Activity to "standard" or "singleTop" this problem is solved.

example:

```
android:launchMode="standard" //This is the default so if you remove the 
                              //attribute "android:launchMode=" from manifest 
                              //file you should be ok as well.
```

instead of

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

I hope this helps out anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is to try using an Intent Filter in your Android manifest and limiting the intents to the single activity you're trying to get a result from.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. I am creating the intent like this: "Intent intent = new Intent(_context, QuickReplyActivity.class);" There is no need for any filter as I am the only one who can call this Activity. Make sense?

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps use an asynchronous task and return the value within doInBackground(Void... params){}

and force the activity to finish in onPostExecute(){}

Comment: Well, that may solve the issue but my understanding is that the entire point of the method startActivityForResult() is so that you don't have to do any crazy hack. I am certain that there is a way to do this, I just need some help figuring out why my Activity behaves differently than another apps Activity and how to get them to behave the same.